# returning a cube function

Tags: python

I have two functions cube which returns a number cubed and by_three which, if cube is divisible by 3, I need to return cube, else return false. here is what I have so far(below). I keep getting the "Oops, try again. by_three(3) returned True instead of 27 " error, some please help if you know what im doing wrong, or perhaps idiotic!.

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3
def by_three(number):
    return number%3==0
    if bythree(number):
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return false
```

Comment: The return value of `by_three` is always `number%3==0`.

Comment: In `by_three` function, you are `return`ing before doing any check in your `if-else` block

Comment: Did you make a mistake formatting your indentation when posting the question or is by_three trying to call itself from unreachable code?

Comment: One more thing, in Python, it is written as `False`, not `false`. `false` is for other languages like Java

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is all over the place but this will do what you want:

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3

def by_three(number):
    return number%3==0

def main(number):
   return cube(number) if by_three(number) else False
```

`if by_three(number)` is True `cube(number)` will be called and returned else just False will be returned.

Your code is either unreachable after the return or you have it outside the function where a return will not work. There is also no `false` in python it is upper case `F`  `

Answer (score 0):

You need a third method.

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3

def by_three(number):
    return number%3==0

def whattodo(number):
    if by_three(number):
        return str(cube(number)) #We must return one type, so we return string for both false and number
    else:
        return "false"

try:
    print int(whattodo(input("Enter a number")) #We are trying to convert the string into an integer

except ValueError: #What if it is not a number? (In this case, it will be a string whose value is "false"
    print "Your number is not divisible by three. Screw you"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```